# Mac Ventura Password suggestions box won't go away

Tags: password, ventura

After updating to Ventura a new username recommendation box has appeared in pretty much all my apps and I don't know how to disable it. I have 1password, the one I want, but it always appears behind the other suggestion box. This box appears for a majority of apps like chrome, firefox, and some other ones that have a username/password field.

I've disabled each browsers password saving, but I know that's not it because it shows up in other apps.

This is in chrome, whited out area are the usernames. They are in a separate box (in front of 1password)

[image]

This image is firefox. The whited out areas are my usernames but they are in a box (not 1password that is behind it)

[image]

Comment: This looks like the auto-suggest feature from 1P. Is the web address in the browsing matching one of the addresses defined for the user names defined in 1P?

Comment: @nohillside it is, however 1password's recommendation is the icon box behind the ones with the whited out username. 1password doesn't recommend w/ two I know this from before updating

Answer (score 1):

- Open System Settings
- Click on "Passwords" (at the beginning of the sixth block of settings)
- Enter your account password
- Click on "Password Options"
- Turn off "AutoFill Passwords"

Comment: it was already off :(

Comment: @NicholasWong Turn it on, reboot, and turn it off again. Wouldn't be the first system setting which gets stuck.